# How to set up proxy in package.json for POST request only?

Tags: node.js, post, proxy, package.json

I have a node app and a create-react-app nested within. Within the development environment, I use concurrently to run two servers, one for the express side, one of the react side.

`localhost:5000` for the node/express side
`localhost:3000` for the React side

At the the moment, I have a sign up page `http://localhost:3000/signup` and when the user presses the 'Sign Up' button, it makes a POST request to `/signup`.

I want it so that **only** the POST request for `/signup` is proxied to `localhost:5000` and not the GET request (which is the view page for the sign up form).

How do I do this?

package.json (in create-react-app):

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": {
    "/signup": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Rest of code: https://github.com/drhectapus/Voting-App

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an option to do the same but with no luck but I found another solution by including a simple configuration in my webpack.

Being more specific the part where I setup the [devServer](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy)

```
devServer: {
  ...
  proxy: {
    '/signup': 'http://localhost:5000'
  }
}
```

Hope it helps to somebody who stucks here too.

I had a demo [here](https://github.com/arkgast/photo-dn).

Regards.